# powershell unable to find type [Windows.UI.Notification]

Tags: powershell

I am trying to generate a windows 10 notification with powershell. The code is as follow:

```
function Show-Notification {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [string]
        $ToastTitle,
        [string]
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $ToastText
    )

    [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
    $Template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText02)

    $RawXml = [xml] $Template.GetXml()
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "1"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastTitle)) > $null
    ($RawXml.toast.visual.binding.text|where {$_.id -eq "2"}).AppendChild($RawXml.CreateTextNode($ToastText)) > $null

    $SerializedXml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $SerializedXml.LoadXml($RawXml.OuterXml)

    $Toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($SerializedXml)
    $Toast.Tag = "PowerShell"
    $Toast.Group = "PowerShell"
    $Toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddMinutes(1)

    $Notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("PowerShell")
    $Notifier.Show($Toast);
}
```

When I run the function, it throws the exception like this: "Unable to find type [Windows.UI.Notificaiotn...."
I think this is a UWP class, but why I can not access this class in powershell ?

Comment: Works for me. You need at least Windows 10 Build 10240 for this (I'm using Version 2004, Build 19041)

Comment: It works on my windows 10 machine.  Can you try an another windows 10 computer?

Comment: What PS are you using? You must use Windows PowerShell (powershell.exe / 5.1-), not PowerShell Core (pwsh.exe / 6.0+).

Comment: Yes, powershell core 7.1 can not support this. I should add winRT manually.

Comment: @Takiya, Can you expand on what you mean by "I should add winRT manually"? Is it a workaround for it to work under PS 7.1? Thanks.

Comment: @woter324, I didn't try that. I see this solution in the powershell github issue.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 22H2 Build 19045.3208 and Powershell 5.1.19041.3031. But still get  "Unable to find type [Windows.UI.Notificaiotn...."